# Solar powered water pump

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, solar-panels, water-tank, cistern

I have really low water pressure in my home at about 15 PSI and sometimes even 0. I already have a check valve on my main 3/4" line from the water meter. Since electricity is pretty expensive where I live (about $0.35/KWH) and also goes out sometimes, I was thinking of getting a solar panel to charge a battery and run a 12 Volt water pump. I would like some recommendations and what I should look for when buying the water tank, pressure tank, pump, battery, and solar panel.

Would a 100 Watt solar panel connected to a charge controller to charge and maintain a car 12 Volt battery connected to a 12 Volt 5GPM water pump be ok?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a city or town water supply, ask the water authority as to why your pressure is that low and what steps they can take to increase the pressure.Has the water supply pressure always been this low? A 12 volt pump probably will not supply enough volume from the existing supply line for a residence unless you were to add a storage tank to pump fron.

Comment: The water utility is of no help at all. They gave me some lame excuse about the water coming from different sources with different size tubing or something. They even recommend to get a water cistern and pump. It's been like this for years. Unless you can recommend a federal authority I can go for this. Anyways, I'm planning on pumping from a water tank.

Comment: If you are looking for a simple system and fix, why not buy a large non-pressurized tank that can be filled with the present water supply and use a residential pump system for all your needs. You can adjust the output of the pump system to hold the water pressure at any pressure you feel adequate for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts are, use solar panels to trickle charge battery.Your ideas are feasible, Clearly you have a good knowledge. Hope this confirms your plans should be ok. Steve uk engineer. SIze water vessels accurately to avoid flooding, This may not have been done before, Expect set backs. Steve uk engineer.